# Why is the maximum value for tabindex = 32767?

Tags: html, tabindex

From [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex):

> The maximum value for tabindex is 32767

I see the number is 2<sup>15</sup>-1, so it's probably related to 16bit or 32bit integers. But how is this related to HTML? Is it a limitation from the browser? Where does this number come from?

### Update

I don't know why this question got closed.

Yes, W3 defined that this is the maximum for tabindex.
Yes, this number is calculated by 2<sup>15</sup>-1.

What I'm asking is ***WHY** `tabindex`'s maximum value is that*? Is it related to the browser? Operating system? HTML? Screen Readers?

Comment: Since it's exactly (2^15)-1 -- I am assuming that the count starts at 0 which would make sense if, when the browser renders, the tab index is stored in an array.  But 2^15 admittedly seems arbitrary ..  Why not 2^10 or 2^20?   There has to be some logic behind the number.

Comment: Yes... that -1 is because `0-32767 = 32768 numbers`. But as you just said, there has to be some logic behind it.

Comment: Logic: Someone picked it. :)

Comment: @epascarello :-]